# Ul changes all my style

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar and i want to drop the profile tag so I put an `<ul>`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <div class="centrado-fluid">
    <div class="loginregister"></div>
    <div class="espacio"></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="index.php"><p class="menuleft">Home</p></a>
        <a href="pelis.php"><p class="menuleft">Películas</p></a>
        <a href="series.php"><p class="menuleft">Series</p></a>
        <input class="buscador" type="text" placeholder="Busca">
        <a href="apeli.php"><p class="menuright">Añadir Serie</p></a>
        <a href="aserie.php"><p class="menuright">Añadir Película</p></a>
        <ul><p class="menuright">Profile</p></ul>
    </div>
    <hr class="linea">
    </div>

</head>
<body>
```

When I put the `<ul>` the `<p>` profile comes down

This is the css

```
.centrado-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
    height: 44px;
    width: auto;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    background: url("../img/slash-layer.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(99, 99, 130);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.espacio {
    height: 10px;
}

.menuleft {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: hasa;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

.buscador {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 7%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: hasa;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

.menuright {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -2px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: hasa;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

How I can return it up?

Comment: Inside `<ul>` you should use `<li>` not the  `<p>` element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lahmf/KJV8w/ add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` tag has default margin and space like paragraph. So don't use UL tag. Simple use `<p>` tag

Comment: So how I can do a dropabble menu without Ul?

Comment: What structure you want to follow. Which parent and which one  is child?

Comment: I want the menu bar and in the right the dropabble profile

Answer (score 0):

To markup your menu, you can do something like this - **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anHGq/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }    
ul.menu { float:left; width:100%; }
ul.menu li { float:left; margin:0 10px; list-style: none;}
ul.menu a { display:inline-block; padding:5px 10px; background:yellow; }
ul.menu .right { float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has some problems with validity. Try using http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input for checking your code:

1. You are closing `<head>` too late; starting from `<div class="centrado-fluid">` you have to wrap everything inside a `<body>`
2. `<p>` is not allowed inside of `<a>`, but the other way round.
3. The only element allowed as children of `<ul>` is `<li>`

The best way to fix your problem would be to fix your HTML before going for the original problem.